# How to set Weekly format for the DTPicker control?

Tags: vb6

Using VB 6

Am using DTPicker Control, In that I want to display weekly like

```
01/07/2009, 08/07/2009, 15/07/2009 so on…,
```

If I am selecting a date after 01/07/2009, it should Display 08/07/2009, if I am selecting a date after 08/07/2009, it should display 15/07/2009.
If am selecting a date before 01/07/2009, It should display 25/06/2009, if I am selecting a date before 08/07/2009, it should display 01/07/2009

Like that I want to display a date.

Need VB 6 Code Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (`DTPicker1` should be replaced by the name of your DTPicker control):

```
Private Sub DTPicker1_CloseUp()
    DTPicker1.Value = DateAdd("d", 7 - DTPicker1.DayOfWeek, DTPicker1.Value)
End Sub
```